# chai equivalent of jasmine.any?

Tags: chai

I have an assert failing:

Assert: `expect(obj1).to.deep.eq(expected);`

It fails because obj1 has an updatedAt timestamp:

`"updatedAt": 1510356196161`

I want to be able to say on `expected`:

```js
{
    updatedAt: chai.any(number),
}
```

The equivalent of jasmine.any. Does this or a similar concept exist in chai?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, looks like the feature isn't implemented yet: https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/644#issuecomment-336197639

The best way to do such assertions that I've found so far is prop-by-prop:

```
expect(obj1).to.have.property('updatedAt').that.is.a('number');
expect(obj1).to.have.property('deletedAt').that.is.a('null');
expect(obj1).to.have.property('name').that.equals('John Doe');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
expect(obj1.updatedAt).to.be.a('number');
```

Comment: That works, but I want to compare the several other properties doing a deep equal. This is specifically what jasmine.any is intended for. I'm wondering if chai also has a similar feature.